# Getting a return value from a func in another class

Tags: ios, swift, class, delegates

I have two classes in swift, `TestView()` and `compileResults()`.

I have functions in `compileResults()` that return a value. I need that value returned to `TestView()`.

I have managed to SET a value in `compileResults()` from `TestView()` but I can't seem to return one.

I've set up a delegate in the same way I'm using delegates elsewhere but it still doesn't seem to yield results.

TestView:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TestView: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

    weak var resStartDelegate: ResStartDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resStartDelegate?.setConTypeResult(val: "WiFi")
        print("ConType is: ", resStartDelegate?.getConTypeResult()) //outputs value nil
    }
```

compileResults:

```
import Foundation

protocol ResStartDelegate: class {
    func getConTypeResult() -> String
    func setConTypeResult(val: String)
}

var testViewDelegate = TestView()

var theTestResults : [String: String] = [
    "conType": ""
]

class complileResults : ResStartDelegate {

    init() {
        setDelegate()
    }

    func setDelegate() {
        testViewDelegate.resStartDelegate = self
    }

    func resetResults() {
        theTestResults["conType"] = ""
    }

    func setConTypeResult(val: String) {
        theTestResults["conType"] = val
        print("Just set contype to: ", theTestResults["conType"]) //prints correctly what has been passed from TestView
    }

    func getConTypeResult() -> String {
        return theTestResults["conType"] ?? "Err"
    }

}
```

EDIT: This seems to work as I want it to, anything wrong with it?

compileResults.swift

```
import Foundation

class complileResults {//: ResStartDelegate {

    var theTestResults : [String: String] = [
        "conType": "",
        "date": "",
        "time": "",
        "jitter": "",
        "loss": "",
        "dspeed": "",
        "uspeed": "",
        "delay": ""
    ]

    func setConTypeResult(val: String) {
        theTestResults["conType"] = val
    }

    func getConTypeResult() -> String {
        return theTestResults["conType"] ?? "Err"
    }
}
```

TestView.swift

```
var comResClass = complileResults()

    class TestView: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            comResClass.setConTypeResult(val: "WiFi")
            let ct = comResClass.getConTypeResult()
            print("CT ", ct)
        }
}
```

Comment: Your edited would work though it is not as abstracted as your prior attempt (protocol way), other than that its fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do this.

```
    class complileResults {

    var theTestResults : [String: String] = [
        "conType": "",
        "date": "",
        "time": "",
        "jitter": "",
        "loss": "",
        "dspeed": "",
        "uspeed": "",
        "delay": ""
    ]
}

class TestView: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

    let result = complileResults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        result.theTestResults["conType"] = "WiFi"
        print(result.theTestResults["conType"] ?? "Err")
    }
}
```

Or this one which is a bit more generic.

```
class orcomplileResults {

    var theTestResults : [String: String] = [
        "conType": "",
        "date": "",
        "time": "",
        "jitter": "",
        "loss": "",
        "dspeed": "",
        "uspeed": "",
        "delay": ""
    ]

    func setResult(key: String, value: String) {
        theTestResults[key] = value
    }

    func getResult(key: String) -> String {
        return (theTestResults[key] ?? "Err")
    }
}

class orTestView: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

    let result = orcomplileResults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        result.setResult(key: "conType", value: "WiFi")
        print(result.getResult(key: "conType"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vollan, I'll give this a go and report back shortly

Comment: I've made an edit that seems even easier, I'm just not sure if I'm breaking some unbreakable rule. By removing the class itself from compileResults.swift I can GET and SET from my functions without issue

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Having them global (outside of class) makes them useable from everywhere and is really bad practice and will allocate a lot of memory. Didn't my solutions work?

Comment: Ahh so that's why, I knew there would be something wrong. No, I couldn't get that solution to work. The function didn't run automatically. I just wanted to be able to set a var using the return of getConTypeResult in compileResults. So, in TestView, var ct = resStartDelegate.getConTypeResult(). Is that not possible?

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer It's now edited to run automatically, i didn't trigger it because i thought you would trigger it at a specific moment, my bad.

Comment: I literally just updated my OP to something that appears to work well and still has everything contained in a class, can you verify?

Comment: Still a global variable, but i think i see now what you want to do. Give me a secc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192976/discussion-between-dan-james-palmer-and-vollan).

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the `complileResults().setConTypeResult(val: "WiFi")` is a different instance from `weak var resStartDelegate: ResStartDelegate?` that's why you are fetching a nil from `resStartDelegate.getConTypeResult`.

Your protocol should have the `setConTypeResult(string)` method AND change `complileResults().setConTypeResult(val: "WiFi")` to `resStartDelegate?.setConTypeResult(val: "WiFi")`

```
class TestView: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

    weak var resStartDelegate: ResStartDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resStartDelegate?.setConTypeResult(val: "WiFi")
        print("ConType is: ", resStartDelegate?.getConTypeResult()) //outputs value nil
    }


protocol ResStartDelegate: class {
    func getConTypeResult() -> String
    func setConTypeResult(val: String)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I'll take a look at this and report back!

Comment: I've updated my code with your suggestions but it doesn't seem to work. Now, I don't even see the print() output in setConTypeResults

Comment: I've made an edit that seems even easier, I'm just not sure if I'm breaking some unbreakable rule. By removing the class itself from compileResults.swift I can GET and SET from my functions without issue

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer Hmm, is `resStartDelegate` nil? If you choose to go the protocol way kindly show your whole code which didn't work so I can see why, the snippets I made above should work alongside your old code though